# xcodebuild firing after every terminal command

Tags: macos, terminal

After every terminal command, the prompt becomes unresponsive for 2-3 seconds. During this time `xcodebuild` seems to be running:

[image: xcodebuild is here]

Where would this hook be that's causing the `xcodebuild` to be fired? I couldn't find anything in my `.zshrc`.

Answer (score 36):

The problem is that the Xcode license hasn't been accepted so when running git it tries to prompt you for accepting the license. For me running

```
sudo xcodebuild -license accept
```

fixed the issue

Comment: The was exactly happened to me after a new installation of xcode!

Answer (score 11):

In my case, the problem had something to do with Apple's version of Git. I'm using zsh and include the current git branch in my command line, so git runs every time a new command prompt is generated. When I switched over to using Homebrew's version of Git

```
brew install git
```

and opened a new terminal, the problem went away. I'm not sure why Apple's version of git was causing xcodebuild to run every time. This was the bug that helped me figure it out: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/2189

Comment: I did this, took an eternity because homebrew decided to update a bunch of formulas, and unfortunately it didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 6):

According to [this blog](http://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/) `zsh` reads a whole bunch of files on startup (including `.profile`):

[image]

So make sure to check all of them (and also any additional files sourced/called from there).

Comment: @patrix : much obliged... that is **much nicer**. Thx :)

Comment: This chart is amazing, I can't believe I've never seen it until now. Thank you!