# Terminal startup time is very slow

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm a newbie and installed some "xcrun" package long time back to fix an issue. That resulted in my terminal startup to become **extremely** slow. Any ideas how to get around this?

Right now I've upgraded to MacOS Big Sure, but have been facing the issue for quite some time.

My `.bash_profile` looks like this

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
# added by Anaconda3 2019.07 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<
# added by Anaconda3 2019.07 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/Users/akv/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/akv/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/akv/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/Users/akv/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: It is probably not terminal that is slow. It is your shell startup files. What is in them e.g. ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile unless you have changed your shell.

Comment: My system doesn't show a bashrc. Here's my bash_profile. I didn't make any changes.   https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WhHAyJnUqrI0nsLjUjrjfmU2BDg_iP-zrBDXrMWKA7E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Well that is a mess - two copies of anaconda initialisation of which one is incomplete and a totally different python as well which has been edited at least 3 times by you (albeit a program you ran did it). If that is really all - take a backup and delete that file. See if you get the problem If you need anaconda then add that back from the latest release

Comment: Does this answer your question? [xcodebuild firing after every terminal command](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119864/xcodebuild-firing-after-every-terminal-command)

Comment: Can you please verify that you are actually using `bash` by running `echo $SHELL`?